# Rails Helper that identifies file type of url in link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm looking for a helper that changes link_to behaviour if the file is a PDF, i.e. displays a tooltip.

How can I write a helper that overrides link_to only if the file is a pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to change the behavior of `link_to`? For tooltips you need to set the `title` attribute or you use something with javascript. So you don't need to change the default behavior.

```
<%= link_to "A PDF document",
            "/some_file.pdf",
            :title => "Tooltip in Most Browsers"
            #, :class => "pdf %>
```

If you want some fancy cool tooltip try google "jQuery tootltip" or something similar.

your could also add `:class => "pdf"`, to be able to find all pdf links with javascript. In jQuery it could look like this:

```
$('a.pdf');
```

If you make a lot of links like this you can [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it up with this helper:

```
def link_to_pdf(name,path,title)
  link_to name, path, :title => title, :class => "pdf"
end
```